# EmberJS: passing arguments into components

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2fSCHSqoMM) tutorial about Ember.js and I'm struggling understanding a "simple" argument-passing issue.

I have a `product` JSON object:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Headphones",
  "colors": [{
    "color": "red",
    "image": "/assets/images/headphones-red.png"
  },
  {
    "color": "black",
    "image": "/assets/images/headphones-black.png"
  }]
},
...
other products with the same structure
```

and this object is passed to a `Product` component inside the `index.hbs` template like this:

```
<Product @product={{product}}/>
```

Inside the `Product.hbs` template I have the following:

```
<Product::Image @src={{this.productImage}}/>
<Product::Details 
    @name={{@product.name}}
/>
```

`productImage` is defined inside the `Product`'s component associate  `product.js`:

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class ProductComponent extends Component {
    productImage = this.args.product.colors[0].image;
}
```

My question is: why do I have to define a specific component property instead of just doing the same as with the `name` property? Something like this:

```
<Product::Image @src={{@product.colors[0].image}}/>
```

The tutorial doesn't explain it, just says *"args represents the arguments, which is the passing property. That's how we use the passing data inside JS"*.

Can somebody enlight me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is no specific reason of defining a separate property to do that except perhaps that in this particular case it adds readability, i.e. "oh, we pass the product image" rather than "we pass the image value of the first element of the colors array", but I am pretty sure it goes without saying.

It is possible to do that like you proposed, but just with the slightly different syntax. The thing is that hbs doesn't understand `colors[0]`. But it will understand `colors.[0]` or even `colors.0`. Sooo it might be

```
<Product::Image @src={{@product.colors.[0].image}}/>

or

<Product::Image @src={{@product.colors.0.image}}/>
```

And I've played with some other options in the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/df18eef01bb5b06dc1e7699ef633468d?numColumns=2&openFiles=templates.application%5C.hbs%2Ccontrollers.application%5C.js)